# Databaselock, at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

My Database code is-

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyLogin.db";
  public Databaselogin(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     db.execSQL(
              "create table login " +
              "(name text,email text, password text,address text,mobno text)"
              );

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS login");
      onCreate(db);

}
 public boolean insertContact  (String name, String email, String pass,String add, String mobileno)
   {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

      contentValues.put("name", name);
      contentValues.put("email", email);
      contentValues.put("password", pass);  
      contentValues.put("address", add);
      contentValues.put("mobno", mobileno);

      db.insert("login", null, contentValues);
      return true;
   }
 public void closeDB() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        if (db != null && db.isOpen())
            db.close();
    }}
```

initialization code:-

```
public class Fragment2 extends SherlockFragment {
EditText name,email,password,address,mobno;
Button signin;
String uname,uemail,upass,uaddress,umobno;



 private Databaselogin mydb =new Databaselogin(getActivity());
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);


    //name=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.nametxt);

     email=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.emailtxt);
     password=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.passtxt);
     address=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.addresstxt);
     mobno=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobtxt);
     name=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.nametxt);
     signin=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.signinbtn);



     signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        uname=name.getText().toString();
        uemail=email.getText().toString();
        upass=password.getText().toString();
        uaddress=address.getText().toString();
        umobno=mobno.getText().toString();

        if(uname.length()==0|| uemail.length()==0||upass.length()==0)
        {
            showMessage("Error", "Please enter correct Value");
        }
        else
        {
            mydb.insertContact(uname, uemail, upass, uaddress,umobno);
            showMessage("success", "Record Added");
            mydb.closeDB();
        }


        }
    });


        return rootView;    

}
 public void showMessage(String title,String message)
    {
        Builder builder=new Builder(null);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.show();
    }

}
```

Get Following Error:-

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
    at com.example.loginslidingmenu.Databaselogin.insertContact(Databaselogin.java:47)
    at com.example.loginslidingmenu.Fragment2$1.onClick(Fragment2.java:57)
```

How can solve this plz reply me.

Comment: This code needs to be narrowed down quite a bit.  Take out all the parts that are not causing the error, then we can more easily help you find the solution to the error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the main issue is that you're calling `getActivity()` pre-maturely, and passing in a null `Context` to the `Databaselogin` constructor.

```
//private Databaselogin mydb =new Databaselogin(getActivity()); //you cannot use getActivity() here
private Databaselogin mydb; //just declare instance variable

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
    mydb =new Databaselogin(getActivity()); //Add this here
    //.......
```

Another issue is that you are calling `getWritableDatabase()` more than once without closing the previous `db`.

Your `closeDB()` method is not implemented correctly, if you want to use a method like that to close the db, you would need to make `db` an instance variable.  As it is now, it calls `getReadableDatabase()` and then calls `close()` on that new `db` instance, in effect doing nothing.

It would be a better design to just close the db in your `insertContact()` method, and any other method that calls `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()`.

```
public boolean insertContact  (String name, String email, String pass,String add, String mobileno)
   {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

      contentValues.put("name", name);
      contentValues.put("email", email);
      contentValues.put("password", pass);  
      contentValues.put("address", add);
      contentValues.put("mobno", mobileno);

      db.insert("login", null, contentValues);

      db.close(); //Add this here!
      return true;
   }
/* get rid of this method, it's not needed
 public void closeDB() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        if (db != null && db.isOpen())
            db.close();
    }
*/
```

Then when you call the method, no need for the extra call to close the database:

```
 mydb.insertContact(uname, uemail, upass, uaddress,umobno);
 showMessage("success", "Record Added");
 //mydb.closeDB(); //not needed anymore!
```